# Why is Tkinter columnspan being ignored?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a data input form in Python 3 on Android (Pydroid3) and cannot get colspan to work as I want it to. The two relevant classes are

```
class LabelledInput(tk.Frame):
    '''A widget combining both a label and an input widget'''
    def __init__(
            self,
            parent,
            label='',
            input_class=ttk.Entry,
            input_variable=None,
            sticky=(tk.E + tk.W),
            label_position=tk.N,
            padding_x=(0, 0),
            padding_y=(0, 0),
            *args,
            **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        
        input_args = {}
        grid_position = {}
        
        #Check if label_position is valid and default to tk.N if not
        if not (label_position in (tk.N, tk.S, tk.W, tk.E)):
            label_position = tk.N
        
        # Set up the grid positions for label and input widget
        if label_position == tk.N:
            grid_position['label'] = {'row':0, 'col':0}
            grid_position['input'] = {'row':1, 'col':0}
        elif label_position == tk.S:
            grid_position['label'] = {'row':1, 'col':0}
            grid_position['input'] = {'row':0, 'col':0}
        elif label_position == tk.W:
            grid_position['label'] = {'row':0, 'col':0}
            grid_position['input'] = {'row':0, 'col':1}
        elif label_position == tk.E:
            grid_position['label'] = {'row':0, 'col':1}
            grid_position['input'] = {'row':0, 'col':0}
        
        if input_class in (ttk.Checkbutton, ttk.Button, ttk.Radiobutton):
            input_args["text"] = label
            input_args["variable"] = input_variable
        else:
            self.label = ttk.Label(self, text=label)
            self.label.grid(
                row=grid_position['label']['row'],
                column=grid_position['label']['col'],
                sticky=sticky)
            input_args["textvariable"] = input_variable
        
        self.input = input_class(self, **input_args)
        self.input.grid(
            row=grid_position['input']['row'],
            column=grid_position['input']['col'],
            sticky=sticky)
```

to give me a combined label and input widget (to reduce repetitive typing) and

```
class CampaignDetails(tk.Frame):
    '''New campaign dialog'''
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.inputs = {}
        
        campaignEntry = tk.LabelFrame(self, text='Campaign Details')
        
        self.inputs['Campaign title'] = LabelledInput(
            campaignEntry,
            label='Campaign title',
            input_variable=tk.StringVar).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
            
        self.inputs['Ruleset'] = LabelledInput(
            campaignEntry,
            label='Ruleset',
            input_variable=tk.StringVar).grid(row=1, column=0)
            
        self.inputs['Version'] = LabelledInput(
            campaignEntry,
            label='Version',
            input_variable=tk.StringVar).grid(row=1, column=1)
        
        campaignEntry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
```

for the actual form itself. However, no matter what I try, the Campaign title widget is stubbornly one column wide. As written above, it is centered in the frame. If I add sticky=tk.W + tk.E, it left justifies, but remains the same width. If I try any form of campaignEntry.columnconfigure to try and set the weight, the overall width of the form changes, but Campaign title remains one column wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `columnspan` *is* working. You didn't tell the widget to fill the space that was allocated to it, so it remains its natural size and centered in the space.

You need to use the `sticky` attribute if you want the widget to fill all of the space it is allocated.

```
self.inputs['Campaign title'] = LabelledInput(...).grid(..., sticky="ew")
```

You also need to use `columnconfigure` to give a weight to the first column in the `LabelledInput` frame so that the column expands to fill unallocated space in the frame.

```
class LabelledInput(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ...
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you - it never occurred to me to put the columnconfigure inside the LabelledInput class, I was trying to set it up inside the form itself.

Comment: @DavidShaw: as a rule of thumb, you should give a weight to at least one row and one column in every widget that has children managed by `grid`.

Comment: If this answer does what you want @David, tell the community by ticking it as correct.